# Remove a subscription

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using a library (Polidea-BLE || react-native-ble-plx) to connect to an external device and recover information.

Basically I read some informations from external device and then I should pass these informations to another page to wrote in the db.

My problem is that I don't understand how to stop the reading, because at the moment I read data and directly pass these to another page.

They said that:

> monitorCharacteristicForService also returns subscription with
>   remove() function so setting transactionId is not necessary.

But I don't understand how to use.

This is my code:

```
async setupNotifications1(device) {
    var timeagm = 0
    var time = 0
    const service = this.serviceGeneral();
    await device.monitorCharacteristicForService(service,this.AccGyrMg, (error, characteristic) => {
        if (error)
        {
          this.error(error.message);
          return;
        }
        const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
        const [...acc_dx] = [2, 4, 6].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({acc_dx,array_acc_dx: [...state.array_acc_dx,[timeagm, acc_dx]]
        }));

        timeagm += 20
      }
    );

      await device.monitorCharacteristicForService(service,this.Pressure,(error, characteristic) => {
        if (error)
        {
          this.error(error.message);
          return;
        }
        const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
        const [...pressure_dx] = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8].map(index => buf.readUInt16LE(index));
        this.setState(state => ({pressure_dx,array_pressure_dx: [...state.array_pressure_dx,[time, pressure_dx] ]
        }));
        time += 20
      }
    );
```

and when the user click on a stopButton I pass the data without stop the reading ( at the moment and this is what I should correct)

```
stopConnection() {
        console.log("Inizio stopConnection");
        Actions.registerattivita(
        {
          array_acc_dx: this.state.array_acc_dx,
          array_pressure_dx: this.state.array_pressure_dx,
      }
      )
  }
```

In your opionion how can I do to use this remove() to stop the reading of data? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.subscriptionMonitor = device.monitorCharacteristicForService(...)
```

and then in `stopConnection()`

```
if(this.subscriptionMonitor) {
    this.subscriptionMonitor.remove()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do you mean with if(this.subscriptionMonitor) ? Thank you

Comment: And also if I console.log(this.subscriptionMonitor.remove() ) it gives me the message:  undefined

Comment: @Jack23show if it gives you undefined it means that this.subscriptionMonitor is not set

Comment: And what do you think could be the problem? I have done as you wrote

Comment: @Jack23 is important to have async await?

Comment: No it's not, do you suggest to delete?

Comment: And one more thing, as you can see I have more than one device.monitorCharacteristicForService(...) I have done for all this.subscriptionMonitor = device.monitorCharacteristicForService(...) it's right?

Comment: @Jack23 yes delete it, and you have to do this.subscriptionMonitor1 and this.subscriptionMonitor2 to manage both

Comment: Just last question, in the if I should insert all the this.subscription?

Comment: you should create two if statement, one for each subscription